# How can I .wrap an element and all of it's unknown siblings

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `.wrap` to wrap all video embeds in a responsive container.

```
  var $iframeVideo = $('iframe[src*="youtube.com/embed"], iframe[src*="player.vimeo"]');
  $iframeVideo.each(function () {
    // Add wrapper to make video responsive
    $(this).wrap('<div class="video-wrapper"></div>');
  });
```

The problem is that sometimes the video may have a sibling caption div which also needs to be wrapped. Sometimes it may not. In the future there may be other elements with different classes. How can I wrap all siblings of the video with the video wrapper class?

```
  <iframe type="text/html"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ youtube_id }}?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay={{ autoplay }}"
    frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
  <div class="sibling"></div>
  <p class="another sibling"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `jQuery.siblings()` to select the siblings of an element, then `jQuery.addBack()` to add the iframe back to the selection. Then you'll need to use `jQuery.wrapAll()` instead of `wrap()` so that the wrapper encloses all of the elements instead of creating separate wrappers for each.

```
var $iframeVideo = $('iframe[src*="youtube.com/embed"], iframe[src*="player.vimeo"]');
$iframeVideo.each(function () {
    // Add wrapper to make video responsive
    $(this).siblings().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="video-wrapper"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Will addBack work if the iframe is not the first sibling?

Comment: Yeah, addBack just adds the most recent selected element set to the current set.